# ADF Dataflow expression builder taking the expression itself as the string

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

This is an odd one.

I'm using ADF to combine many parquet files into one parquet file. This is the second data flow in an ADF pipeline. The first creates the parquet files (all 300 of them).

The sink transformation is taking the literal expression as a string and saving the file as that in my data lake storage.

I use this expression multiple times in my pipelines. I've deleted and re-added the transformation, there are no spaces before the entry.

I'm stuck. Any thoughts?

EDIT:

I put a toString before 'concat', which worked. But this should not be necessary at all.

[image: expression builder]

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in my environment, and it worked for me make sure you are using correct parameters.

```json
concat('100/103','/', $dateToProcess,'/','daily-processedon-', toString(currentDate(), "yyyy-MM-dd"),'.parquet')
```

[image]

Also check the dataflow parameter value if is getting correct.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]